# svn checkout fails on Mac OS 10.8.2 at SSL handshake

Tags: macos, svn, openssl, collabnet

I have set up CollabNet Subversion and now I am trying to check-out some repository from my Mac 10.8.2. I have checked-out the repository successfully from a Windows 7 using the exact same command on the same network:
svn co https://myserver.com/svn/repository repository --username=USERNAME

On Mac OS I get the error:
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://myserver.com/svn/repository': SSL handshake failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856 (https://myserver.com)

BTW: I can access the repository from the Safari Browser with the same URL.

I could not find anything about the error code.

I am running on **Mac OS 10.8.2**

**svn, version 1.6.18** (r1303927)
   compiled Aug  4 2012, 19:46:53

**OpenSSL 1.0.1c** 10 May 2012

which all came with the XCode Developer Tools.

Has anybody an idea what is going on or can recommend any solutions?

The **SubvesionEdge Server** software version is: **3.2.2**-3395.103 with **Subversion version: 1.7.8**-3395.103, **OpenSSL on Server: 1.0.0j**

Who was able get svn check-out working on Mac OS 10.8.2 and which version of svn, openssl and SubversionEdge did you use?

Thanks,

Nelson

Answer (score 0):

That error code looks bogus (336032856 is 0xC84A8B70):

```
$ openssl errstr 0xC84A8B70
error:C84A8B70:lib(200):func(1192):reason(2928)
```

Usually you get a somewhat useful string, like the reason, the source file and line number.

---

```
OpenSSL on Server: 1.0.0j
```

That's a TLS 1.1 server.

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

That's a TLS 1.2 client.

They should inter-operate OK.

---

Try dropping the `--username=USERNAME`, and let `svn` prompt you for it when needed.

---

Did you get prompted to trust the the certificate? Perhaps the SVN server is misconfigured.

---

Finally, [Super User](https://superuser.com/) might be a better place for this. (I personally don't care, but there are folks who like to close questions and downvote for any reason. They hunt in packs).